# iOS Push notification service extension (didReceive) is not called

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

- I've set up the push notification service extension in xCode.
- I've set target Deployment version to 13.0 (app is 13.0 as well)
- `Info.plist` of an extension has correct `NSExtensionPrincipalClass`
- To test, I'm running extension target and selecting app
- I'm testing everything on a device that's running iOS 14.2
- I've tried following payload:

```
{
      "gcm.message_id" : "XXXXX",
      "type" : "XXXXX",
      "url" : "XXXXX",
      "body" : "XXXX",
      "title" : "XXX",
      "google.c.a.e" : "XX",
      "aps" : {
        "mutable-content" : 1,
        "alert" : {
          "title" : "Test",
          "body" : "Test"
        },
        "category" : "XXXX",
        "content-available" : 1
      },
      "channel_id" : "XXXX"
}
```

I also tried excluding `mutable-content` but service extension still didn't get called.
I also tried with simpler payload like this:

```
{
"aps" : {
        "mutable-content" : 1,
        "alert" : {
          "title" : "Test",
          "body" : "Test"
        },
        "category" : "XXXX",
        "content-available" : 1
      }
}
```

No luck here either, both with and without `mutable-content`

I can always see a push notification as a result of testing but the breakpoint in extension `didReceive` method is not triggered. Also the payload is not modified in any way.

Methods like restating device, restarting macbook and deleting derived data didn't work as well

Comment: related Question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66259849/7698092

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this buy deselecting `Copy only when installing` in ***app target -> Build Phases -> Embed App Extensions***

[image]

Comment: Any explaining, why did you have to do it for it to work? I was able to solve this because of your answer. Thanks

Comment: It's probably because "Copy only when installing" doesn't run the app extensions when you build the app using xcode but only on app install. By deselecting this flag, app extension always runs.