# Why notification service extension is not firing on iOS 14?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have integrated [UNNotificationServiceExtension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension) which allows me to change the push notification title before it's presented to the user.

I have followed the guidelines mentioned in [apple developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/modifying_content_in_newly_delivered_notifications) and also browsed related questions at SO, But nothing seems to be working.

---

### As directed, i have followed these guidelines

- Include "mutable-content": 1 in your push notification payload
- Extension's deployment target should be set correctly (should match with main app target)
- The payload must include an alert dictionary with title, subtitle, or body information
- The 'aps' dictionary in payload of the push notification must include a key 'category' with a string value.

---

### The problem

My notification service extension is not triggered sometimes when push notification is received, mostly when i delete and install a fresh copy of app. Breakpoints also don't get triggered in this case. It looks like system forgets to fire the service extension. I have selected the correct scheme of extension and not the main app target. My notification title is not updated as per my logic.

**Note:** This is occurring on iOS 14. on iOS 12, it is working fine. Is this an iOS **bug**?

This is already being discussed in these threads.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/67202
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/125987

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

### Sample Code

I made a sample project to demonstrate this issue. You can download it from [Github Repo](https://github.com/AwaisFayyaz/notification-service-extension-test)

### Related WWDC Video

[Best Practices and What’s New in User Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/708/?time=1358)

Comment: it was fired for me only when using Push Notification Console from WWDC 2023 https://developer.apple.com/notifications/push-notifications-console/

Answer (score 4):

The only solution that was worked for me (21/07/2023) is :

1. Uncheck "Copy When Installing".
2. Remove the notification service extension from "Frameworks" and add it again (re-boot your iPhone).

Answer (score 2):

You have to modify the UNNotificationRequest content part. Below is the code snippet which I have used for my notification extension.

```
import UserNotifications

class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {

    var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
    var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?

    override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
        self.contentHandler = contentHandler
        bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)
        
        if let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {
            var urlString:String? = nil
            if let urlImageString = request.content.userInfo["urlImageString"] as? String {
                urlString = urlImageString
            }
            // You can set what ever title you want to set
            bestAttemptContent.title = "Your custom tile goes here"
            if urlString != nil, let fileUrl = URL(string: urlString!) {
                print("fileUrl: \(fileUrl)")
                
                guard let imageData = NSData(contentsOf: fileUrl) else {
                    contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
                    return
                }
                guard let attachment = UNNotificationAttachment.saveImageToDisk(fileIdentifier: "image.jpg", data: imageData, options: nil) else {
                    print("error in UNNotificationAttachment.saveImageToDisk()")
                    contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
                    return
                }
                
                bestAttemptContent.attachments = [ attachment ]
            }
            
            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
        }
    }
    
    override func serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() {
        if let contentHandler = contentHandler, let bestAttemptContent =  bestAttemptContent {
            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
        }
    }

}

@available(iOSApplicationExtension 10.0, *)
extension UNNotificationAttachment {
    
    static func saveImageToDisk(fileIdentifier: String, data: NSData, options: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> UNNotificationAttachment? {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let folderName = ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString
        let folderURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(folderName, isDirectory: true)
        
        do {
            try fileManager.createDirectory(at: folderURL!, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            let fileURL = folderURL?.appendingPathComponent(fileIdentifier)
            try data.write(to: fileURL!, options: [])
            let attachment = try UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: fileIdentifier, url: fileURL!, options: options)
            return attachment
        } catch let error {
            print("error \(error)")
        }
        
        return nil
    }
}
```

The JSON payload which I have used

```
{
  "aps": {
    "alert": {
      "title": "title",
      "body": "Your message Here"
    },
    "mutable-content": 1
  },
  "urlImageString": "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg"
}
```

with your code repo the output which I am getting is as
[image]

If you want to debug the Notification Service extension then you have to select the Notification Service Extension scheme from the drop down and then your breakpoints will work for you

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have added a link to Github repo. i am already modifying the UNNotificationRequest. Please have a look at sample code

Comment: Please test it on iOS 14. furthermore, please delete and reinstall the app, then send a notification to reproduce this. you can do this multiple times and the problem will be reproduced. Make sure to use the latest push notification token after deleting and reinstalling the app

Answer (score 1):

### Update

I had submitted [Techinical support Incident](https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/) for this issue.  I had performed extensive R & D on the notification service extension. implemented it according to apple docs in a vanila project. Our configuration and everything seemed to be correct. So i requested apple technical support on the issue and got this reply.

> We have determined that you are seeing this issue due to a bug in iOS.
> Please submit a complete bug report regarding this issue using
> Feedback Assistant (https://feedbackassistant.apple.com). For more
> information on Feedback Assistant, please visit
> https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/.
>
> Please include all the information you provided me once again in the
> bug report (you can attach the logs directly to the bug report). Please make sure to follow the instructions at https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/profiles-and-logs/ and follow the instructions for APNS (Apple Push Notification Service) to install a logging profile on your device, and make sure it is installed before reproducing the problem.
>
> **Important**: In Feedback Assistant, when filing bug reports about an
> API/SDK on macOS, iOS, watchOS or tvOS, please select an appropriate
> API/SDK area (after "Something else not in this list”).

So, i am going to submit a **bug report** to apple. i will update this answer once got reply on the bug report.

Comment: Do you have any update regarding this? We have similar issue, after adding notiification extension for loading image in Push Notification, notification is not coming in iOS 14.2

Comment: I tried to reproduce this for submitting bug report to apple. But it was not reproduced. I will try later.
BTW, notification coming or not coming is a separate thing. in my case, notification always comes, but my service extension is not doing it's work

Comment: I believe I'm also experiencing the same issue. Did you manage to get it working? Or can you confirm it's an iOS bug?

Comment: @Alexis As you can see in my answer, these are the words of apple technical support. They confirmed that this is a bug in iOS and told me to File a bug report. I have yet to file a bug report.

Comment: Hi @AwaisFayyaz, any update on this? Recently many of my customer report same issue like this

Comment: @TiếnNguyễnHữu I was busy so could not filed a bug report.

Comment: @AwaisFayyaz hello, I have the same issue in iOS 17.2. Did you manage to fix that?

Comment: @Taras. I could not get a chance to submit a bug report to Apple. I have moved to other projects. If you are having this issue, please file a bug report and update in this thread. Thanks.

Comment: @AwaisFayyaz so it fires only when I use the push notification console https://developer.apple.com/notifications/push-notifications-console/. But if I use Postman it's not fired